# Derivative of $\frac{\mathrm{trace}(A_1X)}{\mathrm{trace}(A_2X)}$ with respect to $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative, trace

What is the derivative of $\frac{\mathrm{trace}(A_1X)}{\mathrm{trace}(A_2X)}$ with respect to $X$, where $A_1, A_2$ and $X$ are all Hermitian matrices?

---

We know that $\frac{\partial(\mathrm{trace}(A_1X))}{\partial(X)}=A_1$ and $\frac{\partial(\mathrm{trace}(A_2X))}{\partial(X)}=A_2$.

Can we do the following:

$$\frac{\partial(\frac{\mathrm{trace}(A_1X)}{\mathrm{trace}(A_2X)})}{\partial(X)}=\frac{\frac{\partial(\mathrm{trace}(A_1X))}{\partial(X)}\mathrm{trace}(A_2X)-\mathrm{trace}(A_1X)\frac{\partial(\mathrm{trace}(A_2X))}{\partial(X)}}{\mathrm{trace}^2(A_2X)}=\frac{A_1\mathrm{trace}(A_2X)-\mathrm{trace}(A_1X)A_2}{\mathrm{trace}^2(A_2X)}?$$

Comment: Yes, that works! Your expression for the ([numerator layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Numerator-layout_notation)) derivative is correct.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank you!

Comment: It should perhaps be noted, however, that your derivation does not make any special use of the fact that $X$ is Hermitian. This is fine; the same definition describes a differentiable function over all complex square matrices $X$.

Comment: The derivative of a real-valued function should be real-valued and not matrix-valued.

Comment: @WimC If $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, then its derivative (gradient) is $\nabla f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, the vector of partial derivatives with respect to each coordinate. So the derivative here should indeed be matrix-valued.

Comment: @Joppy Just writing $A$ for the map $B \mapsto \operatorname{trace}(A B)$ is confusing at best.

Comment: @WimC As the link in my first comment explains, this is a standard way to express the derivative in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the real case so that all involved matrices are symmetric.

Let
$\phi
= \frac{\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{A}_1 \mathbf{X})}
{\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{A}_2 \mathbf{X})}
= \frac{N}{D}
$.
It follows
$$
d\phi
= \frac{D(dN)-N(dD)}{D^2}
= \frac{D\mathbf{A}_1-N\mathbf{A}_2}{D^2}:
d\mathbf{X}
$$
where $:$ denotes the Frobenius inner product.

The symmetric gradient is
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{X}}
=
\frac{D\mathbf{A}_1-N\mathbf{A}_2}{D^2}
$$